# reset a docker container to its initial state every 24 hours

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I need to reset a moodle docker to its initial state every 24 hours. This docker will be a running a demo site where users can login and carry out various setting changes and the site needs to reset itself every day. Does docker provide any such feature?

I searched for a docker reset command but it doesn't seem to be there yet.

Will such a process of removing and reinitiating docker container work?

```
docker rm -f $(docker ps -a -q)
docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -q)
docker-compose up -d
```

I should be able to do this programatically ofcourse, preferably using a shell script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you do not need to reset just recreate the container is enough but if you bind volumes with the host it will not work if there is anything that pick from persistent storage of the host in `docker-compose up`.

Write a bash script that will run every 1:00 AM or whatever time you want to create fresh container.

```
0 0 * * * create_container.sh
```

create_container.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
docker-compose rm -f
docker-compose up -d
```

or you can use your own script as well but if there is bind volumes the clear that files before creating the container.

```
rm -rf /path/to_host_shared_volume
docker rm -f $(docker ps -a -q)
.
.
.
```

As the behavour of `-v` is different it will create [directory](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) if not exist.

Or if you want to remove everything then you can use [system-prune](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/)

```
#!/bin/bash
docker system prune -f -a --volumes
docker-compose up -d
```

Remove all unused containers, networks, images (both dangling and unreferenced), and volumes.

**WARNING! This will remove:**

```
        - all stopped containers
        - all networks not used by at least one container
        - all volumes not used by at least one container
        - all images without at least one container associated to them
        - all build cache
```